# In python, Initialize matrix with same bool value?

Tags: python

Is possible without any loop all values of matrix  is same ? 
for example :-

```
mat = [[0 for i in range(3)]for i in range(3)]

mat = [False]*(3*3)

print(mat)
```

Comment: Why doesn't the first part work for you?>

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm assuming because he needs to use a different variable for the outer loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the latter is **not** recommended. Lists aren't copied over in python.

```
>>> mat = [[False]*3]*3
>>> mat
[[False, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]
>>> mat[2][1] = True
>>> mat
[[False, True, False], [False, True, False], [False, True, False]]
```

Notice how all the middle cells have turned `True`.

You first approach is correct, but to make it more readable / less confusing, you should use different variable names in the loop.

```
>>> mat = [[False for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
>>> mat[2][1] = True
>>> mat
[[False, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, True, False]]
```

Comment: You can use `i` in both comprehensions, it should work fine.

Comment: Yes, didn't realize that. Got prejudiced due to the comment. Thanks!